# Simplified php code for displaying results

Tags: php, mysqli

Sorry if this have been asked before but I couldn't find what I wanted and I am not strong in PHP.

Right now I have this code, which is supposed to return result for different levels:

```
<div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/B1.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="content_container">
            <?php
                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM floor_directory WHERE level='B1'");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
            ?>
            <h1><?php echo $row['categories']; ?></h1>
            <ul class="shop_listing clearfix">
                <li class="float_left"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></li>
                <li class="float_right"><?php echo $row['unit_number']; ?></li>
            </ul>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/L1.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="content_container">
            <?php
                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM floor_directory WHERE level='L1'");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
            ?>
            <h1><?php echo $row['categories']; ?></h1>
            <ul class="shop_listing clearfix">
                <li class="float_left"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></li>
                <li class="float_right"><?php echo $row['unit_number']; ?></li>
            </ul>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </div>
      </div> and so on...
```

Right now I can only duplicate it in order to fulfil the displaying of result for each individual levels. If let's say the building have 10 levels, is there a way to simplified the coding?

Hope you guys understand. Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: You can use `WHERE level='B1' AND level='L1'` plus if you want one or the other, replace `AND` with `OR`

Comment: Yet, what do you mean exactly by "If let's say the building have 10 levels" ?

Comment: Because I am displaying the results of shop names based on each level floor map. Each floor map have their own map image, so if let's say, the building tower have 10 floors, am I going to duplicate the same code for each individual floor map image?

Comment: I'm afraid that's what you'll have to do, as far as I know. There's probably another way of doing it, but that's about the scope of my knowledge on the subject right now. Plus as to "how" you want to display it may be another factor.

Comment: However, you probably could make use of the [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) function.

Comment: You could also use something to the affect of 
`SELECT * FROM floor_directory WHERE (level = 'A1' AND level = 'B1') AND (level = 'C1' AND level = 'D1');`

Comment: Thanks. I don't know is it going to be what I wanted but I will take a look on that.

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look at the example I put just above. That could work also.

Comment: Have a look at what Vishal posted below, makes sense.

Comment: Added note: You also could have done this `SELECT * FROM floor_directory WHERE level IN (A1, B1, L1);` used in your original code. I just found this now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this:

    <?php
    $levelArray=array('L1','B1','L2','B2');
        foreach ($levelArray as $i=>$level) {
             $data='';
            $img = "img/".$levelArray[$i];
           $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM floor_directory WHERE level='$levelArray[$i]'");
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $data .= '<h1>'.$row['categories'].'</h1>
                        <ul class="shop_listing clearfix">
                            <li class="float_left">'.$row['name'].'</li>
                            <li class="float_right">'.$row['unit_number'].'</li>
                        </ul>';
        }
        echo '<div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="'.$img.'" alt="" />
                <div class="content_container">'.$data.'</div>
          </div>'

        }

     ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Vishal! I guess this is what I wanted. So based on your provided code, I would assume that if next time I have new images, I will just need to update accordingly in this line : $levelArray=array('L1','B1','L2','B2'); ?

Comment: @user1462863 I can answer that and the answer is "yes". Just keep adding on to it, for example: `$levelArray=array('L1','B1','L2','B2','C1','D1','E1');` but the last entry does not take a comma.

Comment: I have tested it and it works great! Thanks Fred and Vishal! =D The problem now I am facing is, for L1, it will display info of the shops on L1. But for L2 and onwards, it will display the shops info of L1 + L2 instead of just showing L2 only. Is that able to solve?

Comment: $data='';just add it inside the foreach loop;

Comment: Hi Vishal, I have another question but I don't know will I be able to add it here. Right now I have 2 different shop names but same category as Cafes. When I display the result, the outcomes are Cafes, Starbucks and Cafes, CoffeeBean. I want it to display as Cafes, Starbucks, CoffeeBean. How can I do that?